# Is there a way to convert a string (ASCII) to Hex in CMake

Tags: string, cmake, hex, ascii, data-conversion

Is there a way to convert a string (ASCII `"a-z, A-Z, 0-9"`) to Hex in CMake?

For example ([ASCII to hex](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html)):

```
"HELLO" --> 0x48 0x45 0x4C 0x4C 0x4F
```

Should be the opposite operation of the following command ([see here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#ascii)):

```
string(ASCII <number> \[<number> ...\] <output variable>)
```

I tried some CMake [math](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/math.html) operations, but it didn't seem to work on strings.

I can implement a function with a big "if" that compares the char input of `"a-z, A-Z, 0-9"` and returns its hex according to the [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/), but I am looking for a smarter/shorter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of CMake 3.18, the inverse operation of `string(ASCII ...)` now exists. Use [`string(HEX ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#hex):

```
set(TEST_STRING "HELLO")
# Convert the string to hex.
string(HEX ${TEST_STRING} HEX_STRING)
message(${HEX_STRING})
```

This prints the following:

```
48454c4c4f
```

so you have to manually add the `0x` prefixes (which is described below in the response applicable for earlier CMake versions).

---

For CMake 3.17 and earlier, I am not aware of any support for ASCII to hex conversions that is native to CMake (i.e. the inverse operation for `string(ASCII ... )` doesn't exist). One work-around is to leverage CMake's [`file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) commands to write the ASCII to a file, then read it as hex. With some additional formatting using [`string(REGEX MATCHALL ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-matchall) and [`list(JOIN ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#join), we can get a string of hex values representing the ASCII inputs:

```
set(TEST_STRING "HELLO")

# Write the ASCII file, then read it as hex.
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/asciiToHexFile.txt "${TEST_STRING}")
file(READ ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/asciiToHexFile.txt HEX_CONTENTS HEX)
message("HEX_CONTENTS: ${HEX_CONTENTS}")

# Separate into individual bytes.
string(REGEX MATCHALL "([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9])" SEPARATED_HEX "${HEX_CONTENTS}")
message("SEPARATED_HEX: ${SEPARATED_HEX}")

# Append the "0x" to each byte.
list(JOIN SEPARATED_HEX " 0x" FORMATTED_HEX)

# JOIN misses the first byte's "0x", so add it here.
string(PREPEND FORMATTED_HEX "0x")
message("FORMATTED_HEX: ${FORMATTED_HEX}")
```

With the input `HELLO`, the output prints the following:

```
HEX_CONTENTS: 48454c4c4f
SEPARATED_HEX: 48;45;4c;4c;4f
FORMATTED_HEX: 0x48 0x45 0x4c 0x4c 0x4f
```

Comment: Could be that you want to update regex to ([A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]) hex digits are 0..9 and A..F

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating this function, based on @squareskittles response:

```
function(STRING_HEX_KEY_TO_C_BYTE_ARRAY STRING_HEX VARIABLE_NAME)
    # Separate into individual bytes.
    string(REGEX MATCHALL "([A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9])" SEPARATED_HEX ${STRING_HEX})

    # Append the "0x" to each byte.
    list(JOIN SEPARATED_HEX ", 0x" FORMATTED_HEX)

    # Prepend "{ 0x"
    string(PREPEND FORMATTED_HEX "{ 0x")

    # Append " }"
    string(APPEND FORMATTED_HEX " }")

    set(${VARIABLE_NAME} ${FORMATTED_HEX} PARENT_SCOPE)
    message(${VARIABLE_NAME}=${FORMATTED_HEX})
endfunction()
```

Use this function to convert string hex to C byte array, like this:

```
STRING_HEX_KEY_TO_C_BYTE_ARRAY("FFFF020200000030" "DEVICE_EUI")
```

Output message:

```
DEVICE_EUI={ 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30 }
```